Why is GIT not recognizing some files to be merged?
Main Branch
Jason_Branch
Hello. I am on VSCode trying to merge Main into Jason_Branch. For some reason, only the files in the day1 folder are merging into Jason_Branch. For some reason it doesn't seem to be recognizing maria.txt and jose.txt. When I try to merge again, it says it is up to date. When I am switching between branches they are clearly different.

Are you using a .gitignore file?
